# PhpStorm marking used CSS selectors as unused

Tags: php, html, css, phpstorm, warnings

I wanted to use PHP in my CSS so I changed the file extension of my `.css` file to `.php` and instead of using `<link>` I used `require_once` to include it into my other file. Now PhpStorm sees the selector in my CSS as "unused" even though everything is working fine and the CSS is applied.

Is there any way to make PhpStorm realise the selector is actually used? Or if that's not possible, can I at least turn the warning off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want mark your directories as `Resource Root` from the context menus on Project window.

You can turn that inspection off from

`[Top Menu]`

File -> Settings

`[Left Pane]`

Editor -> Inspections

`[Right Pane]`

CSS -> Unused CSS selector

by unchecking the box next to it.

Comment: Thanks! Does marking my directories as Resource Root do anything beside making it look clearer?

Comment: Actually it does more than visual clearance. It also allows phpstorm to also help completion of code, for relative paths, and some additional parsing.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-folders-within-a-content-root.html